# How to apply python on BatchStage Hazelcast Jet

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

What I am trying to do is, I am fetching the data from different source and doing grouping and join on them and after that I am getting result in BatchStage and now I have to perform python code on this function but I am not able to do it.

Here is my below code:

```
BatchStage<List<Map<String, Object>>> bd = AggregateData.aggregate(data, Object);
bd1 = bd1.filter(k -> {
                        // some filters
                    });
// Now here after this I want to execute python code:
bd1.apply(mapUsingPython(new PythonServiceConfig()
                                     .setBaseDir("D:/")
                                     .setHandlerModule("take_sqrt")))
                             .setLocalParallelism(1)
                             .writeTo(Sinks.logger());
```

But it is now allowing as I am new to this I am not getting exact syntax, please help me out

Answer (score 3):

`mapUsingPython` transforms `BatchStage<String>` to `BatchStage<String>`, so you first have to explicitly convert your `List<Map<String, Object>>` to string representation.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but is there is any other way to send List<Map> directly to it?